# how to change tinymce image upload dialog?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

Is there a possibility to change image dialog of tinymce?

[image]

I want to add a checkbox (or input) for user to select it wants thumbnail to be created. I was looking for an hour and couldn't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE's image dialog does not have this as a part of its standard distribution but as the editor is released under an open source license you could certainly modify the source code to do what you want.  If you download the dev version of the editor you get the unminified versions of all the plugins.

Comment: I've already downloaded it, but I am struggling to find how they've created ui of that dialog. It's not like summernote where I could easily find html and add mine as I want.

Comment: The documentation covers the types of things that can appear in a dialog: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/dialogcomponents/